# python strftime format variable

Tags: python, variables, strftime

I'm using this prometheus json exporter https://github.com/catawiki/json_exporter and
I can't figure out how to use the strftime parameter. It is required to use the format from https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime. As I understand a string should be defined. If I set:

```
strftime: '%Y-%m-%d'
```

and use the variable as

```
params:
        start_date: $strftime
```

I have this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/json_exporter/main.py", line 257, in run
    self.scrape()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/json_exporter/main.py", line 279, in scrape
    data = render(self.body, variables)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/json_exporter/main.py", line 125, in render
    return Template(tmpl).safe_substitute(variables)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/string.py", line 207, in safe_substitute
    return self.pattern.sub(convert, self.template)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

What is the correct way to use this ?

Thank you.

Comment: for template I tried with and without quotes/double quotes, tried to put strftime('%Y-%m-%d') in the params directly, and even time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').
I have mixed pythin 2 and 3 from my example as a mistake, as I have tested to upgrade python to version 3, no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems to match with documentation, even if the documentation is not really clear about wether `datetime.strftime` or `time.strftime` fields are to be used (but interestingly, both know about `%Y`, event the latter).

Some things to try:

- remove the quotes around your format template.
- specify your template directly in the params, instead of using a link

Also, from the error stacktrace, you are running Python 2.7, which means:

- the documentation you need is [on this page](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html?highlight=strftime#datetime.datetime.strftime). Not sure there would be a difference though.
- you're [2 years out of active support period](https://www.python.org/downloads/), and should seriously consider updating your system.